# How do I get Pyinstaller to work with pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I am trying to turn a program, that uses the matplotlib.pyplot module, into an executable.

The script itself works as intended when run in the terminal, but when I use the executable made by pyinstaller, it shows - "Script failed to execute".
I have narrowed down the issue to the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The .exe will run fine with this code commented out, but that way I am not able to plot graphs using pyplot.

EDIT: I did some research on this and found out it's a known issue with Matplotlib 3.3, so I was able to get around it by uninstalling the current version and using:

```
 pip install matplotlib==3.1.3
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Drag and drop that exe file in terminal and see what error is showing. be sure while converting into exe file do not include --windowed